# How can I enable Street View controls in OpenLayers 2?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers, google-street-view

How can I enable Street View controls when working with a Google Maps layer in OpenLayers 2? I tried following the documentation here: [LINK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#Adding_Controls_to_the_Map)

And came up with this:

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Roadmap", {
    streetViewControl: true
})
```

But it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you can not see the "yellow person" icon on the map view?

Comment: Yes, there are no Street View controls.

Comment: You are right, seem there is no streetViewOptions listed in the Controls documentation page: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control-js.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

Note that the link you included is the documentation of [Google Maps JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/), not OpenLayers. OpenLayers *(passively)* ignores the `streetViewControl` parameter altogether.

The Google OL layer is just a map tiles data source (a wrapper, as explained in [the documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Google-js.html)), it doesn't include any functionality you see on maps.google.com.

Comment: I see. But what about the "mapObject" property of the layer? It seems to be a fully-fledged Google Maps object, with a streetViewControl property. There's no functionality I can use here?

Comment: I did some digging around and it looks like it *used* to be possible - but not with OpenLayers alone, but using the GeoExt library ([LINK](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/14360/6990), note that the demo is no longer available). Either way, this looks like something that would not be allowed by Google's T&C anyway... Sorry for a speculative answer! You could try migrating the question to http://gis.stackexchange.com/ for a more targeted audience.